# HtmlUnit - Get radio by value

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

**How can I, using HtmlUnit, get the specific element?**

My target page contains 9 radios all like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="totalpoll[choices][]" value="9" class="totalpoll-choice-checkbox">
```

The only differentiating part is the value.

I'm learning HtmlUnit so any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
for (DomElement elem : page.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
    if (elem instanceof HtmlRadioButtonInput
            && "<your text>".equals(((HtmlRadioButtonInput) elem).getValueAttribute())) {

        // elem is the radio button your a looking for
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have different id's for each element, or use different name in the name attribute.

Comment: I cannot change any of the HTML itself